# amcharts maps PR polygon

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I want to eliminate the islands marked in the photo, but they are part of the Mayaguez polygon, I do want Mayaguez to appear but I only want to eliminate those islands that do not serve me [I want remove this islands, but are part of the same polygon. the Id is "PR-MG"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOmES.png)

[Another example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgbrt.png)

I tried exclude the polygon, but i need the part in the map, so if exclude this polygon disappear all.

`// Create polygon series var polygonSeries = chart.series.push( am5map.MapPolygonSeries.new(root, { geoJSON: am5geodata_puertoRicoLow, exclude: ["PR-VQ", "PR-CU", "PR-LZ", "PR-MG"] }) );`